# Creating a document via a script library

Tags: lotus-notes, xpages

When a form is saved via a button, I want to also create a new document using the form "MSG", which has fields for message title, body and recipient. At first I thought it might be possible using only a JS library, but now I am unsure. What about opening an unrendered XPage which is bound to that document's form, and inheriting the values into it?

Comment: Why don't you just use a DocumentDataSource and bind the fields to it?   Is there a specific reason why a data source is not possible? A custom control can have its own data source(s). To go smart: put the whole shabeng into a xp:panel and do a partial refresh on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understand your question right: try inserting code like this in XPage's datasource (e.g. document1) postSave event:

```
var doc:NotesDocument=database.createDocument();
doc.replaceItemValue("Form","msg");
doc.replaceItemValue("title",document1.getItemValueString("title"));
...
doc.save(true);
```

Comment: This is perfect, thanks. Follow up question: I tried to neaten it up and make the code easier to reuse by putting it into a JS library, like so -

`function createMessage(recipient, title, message){  
 
 var doc = database.createDocument();
 doc.replaceItemValue("Sender","System Message"); ..
 doc.save(true);
}`

However, if I try and call createMessage() in the postSave event then I get a runtime error [ReferenceError] 'createMessage' not found. Both the custom control and the XPage have the script library added to them as a resource, any idea why it can't find the function declaration?

Comment: Did you put it in a Server Side Javascript library?  When you create a scriplibrary you'l need to pick Server javascript rather than Javascript